# Python 2.7 - how do you write MeCab parsed information to a text file?

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, mecab

I've written a GUI that allows Japanese input and when you go to file > parse writes in to a text file. That text file then gets run through MeCab where spaces are put in between the words. After that it is supposed to be written to the text file once again, so it can be displayed in another GUI window.

The issue I'm having is it doesn't want to write the parsed data to the text file. It has no problem writing it the first time. Also, it prints the parsed info to IDLE no problem as well. Here is the parser and the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: <utf-8> -*-
import sys

import MeCab
import codecs

read_from = open("pholder.txt").read()
mecab = MeCab.Tagger("-Owakati")
output = mecab.parse(read_from)
print output


text = output
write_to = codecs.open("pholder.txt", "w", "utf-8")
write_to.write(text)
write_to.close()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\mecabSpaces.py", line 16, in <module>
    write_to.write(text)
  File "C:\...\codecs.py", line 691, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "C:\...\codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What exactly does `mecab.parse()` return? As in, what do you get if you type `mecab.parse(read_from)` at the command prompt?

Comment: the parse function parses how the Tagger function tells it to parse. That's how I understand it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how to comment with page breaks. This would be a one line parse that would separate test by spaces: print MeCab.Tagger('-Owakati').parse('testtesttest')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parsed data isn't unicode, it's a byte string.

So when you try to write the data to the file, it tries to *decode* it to unicode before *encoding* it to `utf-8`. Since your default codec is `ascii`, but you actually have `utf-8`, it chokes on the first character with byte value of 128 or above.

You should `.decode('utf-8')` the returned data, or else use a `mecab` method that returns unicode data.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think of it like that. I've been messing with so many codecs and encoding decoding, I didn't think about it just being a string. Well, I just got rid of all the ancoding hoopla and appended the write() function to the end of the previous open function, without any encoding and blam. It works. 

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Ah, absolutely will do. I'm still new here, so I'm learning the ropes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's working code. Thanks to agf for helping me pull my head out of my butt.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: <utf-8> -*-
import MeCab

read_from = open("pholder.txt", "r").read()
mecab = MeCab.Tagger("-Owakati")
output = mecab.parse(read_from)
print output

text = output
write_to = open("pholder.txt", "w").write(text)
```